# Beamer with spanish babel and pgfplots

Tags: beamer, pgfplots, babel, spanish

as the title says, I have a problem with babel and the label of the angle ("A") in my figure.
If remove the line of \usepackage[spanish]{babel} or don't lable the angle, all compile without problems. But I can't use both.
I have read in the beamer user manual that ">" symbol may cause problems, and have read several similar problems here in SE, but not one helps with my specific problem.

thanks in advance for any guide to a possible solution. Here a part of the code:

```
\documentclass[10pt,Spanish]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{TIKZ}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
            \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = middle,
            axis equal,
            width=0.9\textwidth,
            height=0.7\paperheight,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            xmin = -5, xmax=5,
            ymin = -5, ymax=5,
            xtick = {0},
            ytick = {0}
            ]
            \addplot[->, very thick, red] coordinates{(0,0)(2,3)} node[midway, left]{$\vec{F}_1$};
            \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:2,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:0,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (axis cs:2,3);
            \pic[draw, ->, "A", angle radius = 0.8cm]{angle = A--B--C};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I have not tested it, but could you try to add TikZs `babel` library as well and see, if this helps?

Comment: Thank You for your comment @StefanPinnow, I have tried the option babel in \usetikzlibrary, it doesn't work.

Comment: You could try `\usepackage[shorthands=off,spanish]{babel}` to see if it makes a difference. Also the `Spanish` option for `\documentclass{beamer}` is probably not needed so that can be removed.

Comment: Thank You very much @Marijn, that works!

Comment: @Marijn, do you want to write an answer or are you ok when we close the question as "solved in the comments"?

Comment: @StefanPinnow actually I tried to find a duplicate for `shorthands=off` but the information is rather scattered across related questions and comments, talking about `\shorthandoff{}` and `usetikzlibrary{babel}`. So I guess it wouldn't be a bad idea to collect the information in an answer here, I'll write it when I have time (somewhere in the next few days hopefully).

Comment: @Marijn An answer would still be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `babel` package defines shorthand characters for a number of languages. A shorthand is a character or character combination that makes it easy to enter language-specific punctuation or disable ligatures. The following code shows the use of shorthands for Spanish and the output of the same code for English, where shorthands are not active:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,spanish]{babel}
\begin{document}
Spanish shorthands are "<characters"> with a special-meaning defined by "`babel"' that can be switched off and on and of"-f again.

\begin{otherlanguage}{english}
Spanish shorthands are "<characters"> with a special-meaning defined by "`babel"' that can be switched off and on and of"-f again.
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For Spanish the following shorthands are defined (see the `babel` [package manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/babel/base/babel.pdf) section 1.10 "Shorthands" with a list for all languages on page 14):

`" . < > ' ~`

To implement the shorthand functionality these characters are made active, i.e., turned into macros. If the characters are used in TikZ code, or in other places where they are expected to have a normal meaning as regular characters, then the code will break. The combination of TikZ with French is notorious for this, because French defines `;` as a shorthand and this character is used very frequenty in TikZ. But for Spanish you can also run into trouble with `"` and `>` as in the example in this question.

You can switch off the shorthands using the `babel` package option `shorthands=off`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{TIKZ}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
            \begin{axis}[
            axis lines = middle,
            axis equal,
            width=0.9\textwidth,
            height=0.7\paperheight,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = $y$,
            xmin = -5, xmax=5,
            ymin = -5, ymax=5,
            xtick = {0},
            ytick = {0}
            ]
            \addplot[->, very thick, red] coordinates{(0,0)(2,3)} node[midway, left]{$\vec{F}_1$};
            \coordinate (A) at (axis cs:2,0);
            \coordinate (B) at (axis cs:0,0);
            \coordinate (C) at (axis cs:2,3);
            \pic[draw, ->, "A", angle radius = 0.8cm]{angle = A--B--C};
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Great answer!!!

Comment: @samcarter I did the other one from your comment yesterday as well.

Comment: Great! The missing language key seems like such a tiny problem, but it is hard to find amongst all these options, so the answer might be very useful for many people